# Withh contact form 7 get custom-fields value

Tags: contact-form-7

In my project, I have some custom fields.

```
$referansno = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_propertyforsale_referansno', true);
```

I like to get `$referansno` value with **contact form 7**.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your goal is.
Can you describe in more detail what you intend to do?

Would you like to display Custom Post Meta in Contact Form 7 and use it as a default value?
Take a look at this:
https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).